# Is a 64-bit character literal possible in C?

Tags: c, gcc

The following code compiles fine:

```
uint32_t myfunc32() {
    uint32_t var = 'asdf';
    return var;
}
```

The following code gives the warning, "character constant too long for its type":

```
uint64_t myfunc64() {
    uint64_t var = 'asdfasdf';
    return var;
}
```

Indeed, the 64-bit character literal gets truncated to a 32-bit constant by GCC.  Are 64-bit character literals not a feature of C?  I can't find any good info on this.

Edit: I am doing some more testing.  It turns out that another compiler, MetroWerks CodeWarrior, can compile the 64-bit character literals as expected.  If this is not already a feature of GCC, it really ought to be.

Comment: Given that a character literal is an `int`, and that `int` on most systems directly maps to `int32_t` I would assume this makes sense... or at least as much sense as using any multi-character literal makes (that is near to none).

Comment: Just **speculating** here, but this observation may come about because the widest character format supported by gcc is a 32-bit `wchar_t` (which can hold a UTF-32 character).

Comment: "If this is not already a feature of GCC, it really ought to be." nah... since the result of conversion of a multi-character is implementation defined it's not useful anyway. It's much better to avoid them.

Comment: Just some wild speculation but would adding `ul` suffix be valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are 64-bit character literals not a feature of C?

Indeed they are not. As per C99 §6.4.4.4 point 10 (page 73 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

> An integer character constant has type `int`. The value of an integer character constant
> containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the
> numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer.
> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
> `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
> execution character, is implementation-defined.

So, character constants have type `int`, which on most modern platforms means `int32_t`. On the other hand, the actual value of the `int` resulting from a multi-byte character constant is *implementation defined*, so you can't really expect much from `int x = 'abc';`, unless you are targeting a specific compiler and compiler version. You should avoid using such statements in sane C code.

As per GCC-specific behavior, [from the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior) we have:

> The numeric value of character constants in preprocessor expressions.
> The preprocessor and compiler interpret character constants in the same way; i.e. escape sequences such as `‘\a’` are given the values they would have on the target machine.
>
> The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated to the width of a target character. The final bit-pattern is given type `int`, and is therefore signed, regardless of whether single characters are signed or not. **If there are more characters in the constant than would fit in the target `int` the compiler issues a warning, and the excess leading characters are ignored.**
>
> For example, `'ab'` for a target with an 8-bit char would be interpreted as `‘(int) ((unsigned char) 'a' * 256 + (unsigned char) 'b')’`, and `'\234a'` as `‘(int) ((unsigned char) '\234' * 256 + (unsigned char) 'a')’`.

Comment: I think it is safe to say I am writing insane C code.  This is for a game modding project, and in the original code, 32 and 64 bit character literals were used quite often as stand-ins for actual strings (probably to avoid using strcmp).  It's a shame 64-bit character literals aren't a thing in the C standard, but I'll find some workaround.  Thank you for your fast and concise answer.

Comment: @MintyMeeo I can't say if making such optimizations makes sense in your case, but modern compilers should already be capable of optimizing comparison of small strings when possible.